# How can I correctly declare an arrow function?

Tags: reactjs

What is the **difference** between

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => handleClick(e));
```

and

```
document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

In the first case I see in the console:

[image: console result]

In the second case:

[image: console result]

**So why sometimes the results are doubled?**

The fragment:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import TodoList from './TodoList'

export default function App () {

  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [todoTitle, setTodoTitle] = useState("");
  const [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = (e) => console.log("click", e.target);

  useEffect(() => {
    const raw = localStorage.getItem("todos") || JSON.stringify([]);
    setTodos(JSON.parse(raw));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("click", (e) => handleClick(e));
    localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));
    
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("click", (e) => handleClick(e));
    }
  })

  const addTodo = event => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      setTodos([
        ...todos,
        {
          id: Date.now(),
          title: todoTitle,
          completed: false
        }
      ])
      setTodoTitle("");
    }
  }
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Todo app</h1>
          <div className="input-field">
            <input
              type="text"
              value={todoTitle}
              onChange={e => setTodoTitle(e.target.value)}
              onKeyPress={addTodo}
              />
            <label>Todo name</label>
          </div>
          <TodoList todos={todos} />
          <button onClick = {() => setChanged(!changed)}>button</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Depends on whether `handleClick` uses `this`

Comment: @SurajRao: No, that's irrelevant here. That's more an issue if you use an *object method* as event handler.

Answer (score 8):

The main difference is that in the first case you are binding `handleClick` directly whereas in the second case you are binding an "intermediate" function that calls `handleClick` instead. The observable result is the same though.

However the reason why you are seeing the output double is that

```
document.removeEventListener("click", (e) => handleClick(e));
```

doesn't work. `removeEventListener` can only work if you pass **the same** function that you passed to `addEventListener`. That's fine if you pass `handleClick`, but it's not possible if you use an "intermediate" function since you are not keeping a reference to that function around.

You could fix that easily:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handler = (e) => handleClick(e)
  //    ^^^^^^^ "remember" the function
  document.addEventListener("click", handler);
  //                                 ^^^^^^^
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos));

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    //                                    ^^^^^^^
  }
})
```

But really there is no need to use an additional function here. That one level of indirection isn't useful. Just pass `handleClick` directly.

Comment: So you mean that when we want to ADD a listener there is no difference, but removal is possible only when you pass the name of the function to "addEventListener" and "removeEventListener"?

Comment: when you use an arrow function somewhere , without storing it in a variable , it has a new reference in the memory each time you write it . so when you are passing an arrow function to `removeEventListener` , it's a new function and is not the same function that you passed to the addEventListener

Comment: too difficult to understand. That is because (e) => handleClick(e) is the object and there are no the same objects? but simple handleClick is a reference to the function?

Comment: @Anthony: Yes. That's not specific to arrow functions though. That counts for an function, simply because two function objects are not never identical, even if they do the same thing: `console.log(function() { return true; } === function() { return true; })`.

Comment: I understood. The last question: "The main difference is that in the first case you are binding handleClick directly whereas in the second case you are binding an "intermediate" function that calls handleClick instead. The observable result is the same though." binding to what? does binding differ in that two cases?

Comment: @Anthony: You can also use the term "assign" if that makes more sense to you. It's just the term I used to express that you are associating a function with an event.